# No matching products found. Please verify that the ProductSet exists, has images and has been indexed. Google Cloud Vision

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am trying to implement Google Could Vision Product Search API in my Android Application. I am at the very first stage of the API. I am following the documentation https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/quickstart step by step. I have successfully created the product set and it is also indexed successfully, but when I search for a product through an image it gives me this error "No matching products found. Please verify that the ProductSet exists, has images, and has been indexed."

**Products indexed successfully**

[image: Products indexed successfully]

**Error when searched through an image**

[image: Error Message]

**Note:-** I am just following the Quick Start Using API just now, and I am stuck at the very first stage. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please cover up your application token on your screenshot, since others might use this and send requests using your token.

Comment: I got the same error as you. I tried providing a base64 image first and it worked. After that, I retried searching using the gcs url and it worked. Then all the succeeding requests using gcs url are all returning the correct results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I will try it now, and tell you if I get succeeded or not.

Comment: Hi, do you any source where I can check how to use product search API in Android? I see examples for Java but not specifically for Android, also they don't have any documentation or project sample for android. I am really confused.

Comment: And why the API is showing display name empty? While I have added the display name with each product.

Comment: Apologies but I'm not very familiar with android, also it might be better to post a new question regarding your inquiry about the API for android and the display name being empty. So the community can share their thoughts on this :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and comment. I really appreciate it. Sure, I will post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Making sure more than 1 image is uploaded as a reference fixed my products and sets that were broken.

I ended up black box testing the Product Search API and found these actions (listed below) did not help. I was also getting no matching products after everything had been indexed:

- Deleting all sets and reinstating them.
- Deleting all products and reinstating them.
- Eliminating all special characters from titles and id's.
- Base64 encoding the image being searched.
- Uploading local images only.
- Uploading remote images only.
- Switching from Python to cURL.
- Making sure each set has more than 1 product.

Comment: Hi, Z Dodds, thank you for your answer the issue is automatically got resolved, I tried the API after two days and it was working perfectly fine, but the only issue now is that the API returning display names empty. Do you know why is it empty?

Comment: Good to hear it's returning results for you now. Regarding the empty display names, I'm sorry to say I don't know what the problem could be there and haven't encountered that myself. If it's really important and doesn't resolve, perhaps a work around would be to cross-reference the id's against a database with the id's and display names and populate them that way.I wish there weren't so many odd behaviors with the API, but good to know we're all in this together trying to figure it out. :)